# Database of major cities&towns of each country with latitude & longitude

Tags: database, city, countries

I´m looking for a database of the **major cities and towns** of each country.

Most services have databases of millions of places (like this one https://www.maxmind.com/en/free-world-cities-database), but for my purposes that is way too detailed.

I think that roughly about 70 places per million people should cover all major places in our world. Therefore I´m looking for a database of about 300 000 - 400 000 entries, all countries listed. The maxmind database could be filtered to only contain the major ones but for most entries the population data is missing.

Anyone know where/how to get such database?

Answer (score 2):

You can use that csv database : http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/cities15000.zip
which contains the worldwide cities (lat,lng) with more than 15000 inhabitants.

Because it also contains the population, you can easily filter to only have very big cities.

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of these :

- [~100 000
  records](https://code.google.com/p/worlddb/downloads/detail?name=worlddb.7z&can=2&q=)
- [~300 000 records but some in specific languages like
  chinese](http://www.opengeocode.org/download.php#cities)

Comment: Thanks Romain! That database looks pretty good for my purposes.